# objective-c prepareForSegue don't see variables in vc

Tags: objective-c

This code isn't able to access a variable from ClubImageViewController:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"mySegue"]) {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        ClubImageViewController *vc = (ClubImageViewController * )navigationController.topViewController;
        vc. //here can't see the var from ClubImageViewController
    }

}
```

#### ClubImageViewController.m:

```
#import "ClubImageViewController.h"
#import "KASlideShow.h"

@interface ClubImageViewController () <KASlideShowDataSource,KASlideShowDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet KASlideShow *slideShow;
@property NSArray* imageArray;


@end
```

What did I miss? Is there something in the storyboard I should change?

Comment: Everything depends on what sort of view controller ClubImageViewController is.  Please post ClubImageViewController.h to tell us.  My guess is that it's not a UINavigationController subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a guess that the `ClubImageViewController` is a regular view controller, and the OP code was picked up in a copy paste where the destination was a navigation controller, some simpler code will work...

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"mySegue"]) {
    ClubImageViewController *vc = (ClubImageViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    // here, all will be fine with the variable vc
}
```

If I'm wrong, and `ClubImageViewController` really is a UINavigationController, then...

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"mySegue"]) {
    UINavigationController *navVC = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    NSArray *viewControllers = navVC.viewControllers;
    ClubImageViewController *vc = (ClubImageViewController *)viewControllers[0];
    // here, all will be fine with the variable vc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//assign an identifier to your segue from StoryBoard with string "mySegue"

```
//And change fetch your ViewController object by getting the root view controller. I mean look at the last line inside your if condition

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"mySegue"]) {
    UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
    ClubImageViewController *vc = (ClubImageViewController * )[navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    vc. //here can't see the var from ClubImageViewController
}
```

**Previous Line**

```
ClubImageViewController *vc = (ClubImageViewController * )navigationController.topViewController;
```

**New Line**

```
ClubImageViewController *vc = (ClubImageViewController * )[navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: how to change fetch?

Comment: "Property 'rootViewController' not found an object of type 'UINavigationController*'; did you mean 'topViewController'?

Comment: Sorry i consider it as UIWindow object instead of UINavigationController

Comment: 2016-12-30 03:00:05.778 clubberExample[12911:994369] -[ClubImageViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdc1361ffd0
2016-12-30 03:00:05.787 clubberExample[12911:994369] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ClubImageViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdc1361ffd0'

Comment: why are you taking your object as array?
use your navigationControllers object